# How can I loop thru a string in model Python?

Tags: python, html, django

I want to show Women League in template and here is my views.py code:

```
leagues = League.objects.all()
for league in leagues:
    print(league.name)
```

It will show me all the name of the leagues which is:

```
International Conference of Amateur Ice Hockey
International Collegiate Baseball Conference
Atlantic Federation of Amateur Baseball Players
Atlantic Federation of Basketball Athletics
Atlantic Soccer Conference
International Association of Womens' Basketball Players
American Conference of Amateur Football
Atlantic Amateur Field Hockey League
Transamerican Womens' Football Athletics Conference
Pacific Ice Hockey Conference
```

And how can I loop thru these name and pick out Leagues that have Womens' in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, use [**`contains`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#contains) or `icontains` because of case insensitive search:

```
leagues = League.objects.filter(name__icontains='women')
for league in leagues:
    print(league.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `league.name` in lower case contains "women" before printing as such:

```
leagues = League.objects.all()
for league in leagues:
    if "women" in league.name.lower():
        print (league.name)
```